# JSONWebService does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i encounter an error in my asp.net c# code

here's the error

'JSONWebService.Service1' does not implement interface member 'JSONWebService.IService1.GetAllAccountClassifications()'

here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JSONWebService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ASDASDASDAS1;Initial Catalog=ULIV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=uliv_user;Password=******");

        public List<wsAccountClassification> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            ULIVDataContext dc = new ULIVDataContext();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from AccountClassifications",conn );

            List<wsAccountClassification> results = new List<wsAccountClassification>();
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

            foreach (AccountClassification AcctClass in dc.AccountClassifications)
            {
                results.Add(new wsAccountClassification()
                {
                    AccountClassificationID = AcctClass.AccountClassificationID,
                    ClassificationName = AcctClass.ClassificationName,
                    ClassificationDescription = AcctClass.ClassificationDescription
                });
            }

            return results;
        }
}
}
```

PLEASE HELP.
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method named `GetAllAccountClassifications` defined in `IService1` interface.You are implementing that interface so you should implement all methods inside of your class that are define in `IService1`.As the error said you should implement `GetAllAccountClassifications` method in this case.